# Find divergence of vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

The vector field $\textbf{F}$ is a function of the position vector $\textbf{r}$

$$\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}) = \frac{\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}_0}{\|\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}_0\|}$$

What would be the divergence $\nabla\cdot\textbf{F}$?
I'm assuming that $\textbf{r}= \langle x,y,z \rangle$

Comment: What does this even mean? Do you want to solve

$$r = \frac{r-r_0}{\|r-r_0\|}?$$

or do your mean to find the divergence of 

$${\bf F} = \frac{{\bf r}-{\bf r}_0}{\|{\bf r}-{\bf r}_0\|}?$$

Comment: the divergence of vector field F

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\parallel r-r_0\parallel}\nabla\cdot(r-r_0)+(r-r_0)\cdot\nabla\frac{1}{\parallel r-r_0\parallel}$